# Returning multiple values from a Group by LINQ statement C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Hi I am having trouble getting the correct values from my group by statement. I am trying to get a value grouped by another value here:

```
var allGuilds = Player.dictGuilds;


var guildTypeRoster =
    from g in allGuilds
    where g.Value.GuildType.ToString() == CBGuildType.SelectedItem.ToString()
    orderby g.Value.GuildName
    group g.Value.GuildServer.ToString() by g.Value.GuildName;
```

So basically I'm trying to group the names in guild by the server they are on. I run into problems when trying to output both the server I am grouping by and the name here:

```
foreach (var pair in guildTypeRoster)
{
    OutputBox.AppendText(pair.Key + "\n");
}
```

I can only get the key of the value which is the names I grouped by. I'm trying to also display the server and have both display but I cannot seem to find a way to do that. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using `pair.Value` to get the value of the key?

Comment: It should be group  new { server = g.Value.GuildServer.ToString(), guildName = g.Value.GuildName}

Comment: @Stemado yeah ive tried pair.value and it does not exist

Comment: You want to *group the names in guild by the server*. So do that. Now you're grouping servers by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to iterate over each group's records so you need an additional loop.

```
foreach (var pair in guildTypeRoster)
{
    foreach(var value in pair) 
    {
        OutputBox.AppendText(pair.Key + ": " + value.GuildName + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked when I used value.ToString() but Im having issues printing since it displays the server twice instead of just once and listiing all guilds

Comment: Change you grouping according to what you need returned; for example: `group g.Value by g.Value.GuildName;`